# Pandas search max value in certain row range in Column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

i have data from series with 5 column and x row

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'name' : ['bill', 'joe', 'steve', 'ana', 'john', 'ray'],
    'test1' : [85, 75, 85, 87,75, 81],
    'test2' : [35, 45, 83, 35, 45, 83],
    'test3' : [51, 61, 45, 51, 91, 45],
    'Highscore' : [85 , 75, 85, 87, 91, 83],
}
frame = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(frame)
```

this the print result

```
        name  test1  test2  test3  HighScore
    0   bill     85     35     51        85
    1    joe     75     45     61        75
    2  steve     85     83     45        85
    3    ana     87     35     51        87
    4   john     75     45     91        91
    5    ray     81     83     45        83
```

How to get maximum value in Column only for certain row range?

```
test1 from 0 to 3 --> 87
test2 from 3 to 5 --> 83
Highscore from 0 to 3 --> 87
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need select values with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and get `max`:

```
a = df.loc[0:3, 'test1'].max()
print (a)
87

b = df.loc[3:5, 'test2'].max()
print (b)
83
c = df.loc[0:3, 'HighScore'].max()
print (c)
87
```